# Spring security change password,then logout,but fail when relogin with new password

Tags: spring, security, spring-security, passwords

i'm dying,i'm dying!
i use
spring 4.1.5.RELEASE
spring-security 4.0.0.RC2
spring-data-jpa 1.8.0.RC1

in my UserController.changePwd() method like below:

```
User currentUser = this.securityUtil.getCurrentUser();
    currentUser.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encodePassword(newPwd, null));
    this.userService.save(currentUser);
    request.getSession()
                .removeAttribute(Constants.SESSION_CURRENT_USER_KEY);
```

after change the password,the request be redirected to /logout

then i checked the database,the password has been changed to new password.

then i relogin with new password,i get the Bad credentials Exception

so i debuged,i found in org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl.loadUsersByUsername(String username) method get a user with old password

only when i restart the server,the new password will be useful.

please help me and thank a lot

Answer (score 0):

Are you using caching in your UserDetailsService? In that case you will need to explicitly reset the cache entry for the user after you changed password:

```
@Autowired
private UserCache userCache;

public void resetPassword() {
   // Change password in DB

   // Now: explicitly expire the user from user cache
   userCache.removeUserFromCache(userName)
}
```

Comment: although i config cache like below:<cache:annotation-driven/>
 <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
        <property name="cacheManager" ref="ehcache"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:cache/ehcache.xml"/>
    </bean>

Comment: My example referred to how you would go about this if you were using built-in Spring Security user caching (which would be the best way to achieve this). The point here is that if the values returned from the UserDetailsService are cached in any way, the cached value for the corresponding user will need to be evicted when you change the password.

Comment: sorry,my last comment is not full,i mean ,although i config cache used by hibernate,but i didn't config a cache named "userCache" used for spring security.so it will be NullUserCache and should load the newest status of user,right?